# How do I make items in the ListBox as headers of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `ListBox`, on_button click, I want all the items in the `ListBox` to be displayed as headers in the `GridView`.
Here is the code that i have tried :

```
protected void DONE4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel7.Visible = true;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(ListBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();

        foreach (GridViewRow grdRow in GridView2.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList bind_dropdownlist = new DropDownList();                                                    // defining the property of the DropDownList as bind_dropdownlist
            bind_dropdownlist = (DropDownList)(GridView2.Rows[grdRow.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("Pro_List"));   // finding the  DropDownList from the gridiew for binding
            SqlDataAdapter mydata = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Profile_Instance FROM Profile_Master", con);
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();                                                                           // binding the DropDownList with the dataset ds
            mydata.Fill(dset, "Table");
            bind_dropdownlist.DataSource = dset;
            bind_dropdownlist.DataTextField = "Profile_Instance";                                                   // set the DropDownList's DataTextField as designation which display the designation in the dropdownlist after fetching the data from database
            bind_dropdownlist.DataBind();
            bind_dropdownlist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Choose Profile---", "-1"));
        }
    }
```

I want all the items in the `ListBox` to be displayed as header field in a `GridView`.

The code above gives no errors, but when run it does not work. Can anyone kindly help me with this?

Here is my Design code for the `GridView`:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel7" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" style="text-align: center; font-size: small">

            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Pro_List" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>                          
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: So in the code that I have posted does not anywhere tell what the content on the `GridView` should be. I have just coded for header and first column of the `GridView`. So is that the reason I am not able to display the `Grid` when I run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the DataSource, call the `DataBind` method and see what happens

```
GridView2.DataSource = dt;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

### Edit

The below code works just fine. Tested.

If you do not have data in the Grid, it won't show anything even the headers unless you give an EmptyText field property value for the grid.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow rw = default(DataRow);
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(ListBox1.Items[i].ToString(),
                                   System.Type.GetType("System.String"));             
}
//Simply adding 10 rows
//Replace this hard coded loop with your looping 
// over your data to add rows.
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    rw = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        rw[ListBox1.Items[i].ToString()] = "Hello there";
    }              
    dt.Rows.Add(rw);
}
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The working sample is available in this [link](http://sdrv.ms/TZMN6v).

Comment: @ArchanaB.R What does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an error message?  Is it spilling your coffee?  What?

Comment: In detail : On_button click, I am suppose to get a `GridView` whose headers are the items in the `ListBox`. And I am adding a `DropDownList` to each row of the first coloumn in the `GridView`. I am wondering since there are no contents in the cells of the `GridView`, it is not displaying anything? Clarify me.I will edit the code part of my question and tell u what exactly I am trying to do.

Comment: @ArchanaB.R: Check the updated answer.I added link to a working sample i uploaded in skydrive. Good Luck