# Sorting ListBox Items to make header in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, listbox

I will refer to this link. [How do I make items in the ListBox as headers of GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113995/how-do-i-make-items-in-the-listbox-as-headers-of-gridview)

giving the link above have the functionality on how to make a list box items be the headertext of a gridview. .  My question would be. If I have a 2 List box. first is consist of numbers, second is name/word. How can I sort the second listbox based on the number on listbox1 then make the output be the header of gridview?.

LBox1 LBox2

3  AAA

2 DDD

1 EEE

5 BBB

4 CCC

GridView Header should be

EEE DDD AAA CCC BBB.
Glad if you could provide sample code.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create a SortedDictionary. this collction automatically sort according to the key.

```
 SortedDictionary<string, string> values = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
```

And then fill data using your two lists

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListBoxnumbers.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            values.Add(ListBoxnumbers.Items[i].ToString(), ListBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
```

after that another loop will fill the headers

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> item in values)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(item.Value, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        }
```

Comment: Got a bit problem, the header is not sorted properly if listbox1 Got value(1,2,14,3,16,5,4) when sorted its (1,14,16,2,3,4,5). .

Comment: Made it work now. change foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> item in values) to foreach (KeyValuePair<int16,string> item in values). and values.Add(ListBoxnumbers.Items[i].ToString() to values.Add(Convert.ToInt16(ListBoxnumbers.Items[i].ToString()) .  and the others